# Spring Integration Http imports not being recognized

Tags: apache, spring-integration

The below imports are not being recognized in my code:

```
org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper
org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler
```

I want to use the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` and `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` in my code but its unable to recognize it.

I have the below dependencies in my gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath('org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7')
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.0'
}
}

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
compile('javax.cache:cache-api')
compile('org.ehcache:ehcache:3.+')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws')
compile('com.h2database:h2')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
compile('org.springframework.retry:spring-retry')
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"
compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10')
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.6.+')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+'
compile 'org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.115'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'

optional('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
optional('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
}
```

Should i be using any other imports or should the version of any dependency be different? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing this one:

```
 compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http')
```

Spring Boot doesn't provide that dependency by default.

Comment: I have another spring app which is using the below build file but it is still able to recognize those dependencies:    `buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
        springIntegrationVersion = '4.2.4.RELEASE'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6"
        classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7'
    }
}
`

Comment: continued from above... `dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
}`

Comment: cntd...`    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-xml')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:1.6'
    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.6.+'
`

Comment: Well, maybe that is an old Spring Boot version there: the HTTP has been dropped since 1.4